# Android | What is the best way to retrieve a contact's photo by phone number?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-contentresolver

I have an application that needs to get the photo of a given contact. I have the phone number of the contact, so is there a way to retrieve the photo of the contact if it exists by phone number via ContentResolver or any other form? I've been searching, but found no answers.

I would really like to stress the importance of using the phone number to get the contact photo if it exists. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out how to add facebook photos. This method will add the facebook photos you need by phone Number:

```
    public Bitmap getFacebookPhoto(String phoneNumber) {
    Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Uri photoUri = null;
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contact = cr.query(phoneUri,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null, null);

    if (contact.moveToFirst()) {
        long userId = contact.getLong(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, userId);

    }
    else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    if (photoUri != null) {
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
                cr, photoUri);
        if (input != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
    } else {
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
    Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
    return defaultPhoto;
}
```

Comment: Cheers up ROFLwTIME , i tried many links but couldnot found anything relevant but your post hit the jackpot

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there's an easy way to do this. But I guess you can go through the Contacts on the phone and check each number if it's the one your are trying to match.

As the numbers are unordered anyway, there's no way to make it more efficient. Search in unordered list is performed by traversing them, as I suggest you should do with this problem. Unless Android keeps all numbers in an ordered list that I don't know about.

You can traverse through the Contacts by doing something like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
   String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
   ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
   String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
   if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
      // You know it has a number so now query it like this
      Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null); 
      while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
         String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));                 
      } 
   phones.close(); 
}
cursor.close();
```

This is not the complete solution to your task, but by modifying the code above I think you'll get through. :-)